# Google Keep Mobile frequently freezes

Tags: google-keep

I use Google Keep a lot and I have many... many notes. Some of these notes were written with the mobile version of Google Keep. However, something that really inhibits my experience with it is the fact that around every ten seconds, the app will just "freeze" and not react for three seconds. I can type all I want, but the text won't appear until it unfreezes and it will ignore backspaces for some reason. Also, sometimes when I edit an already existing note and I leave the app too early, it will just remove all the additional text I typed into the existing note, which I assume is also an effect of this constant freezing.

My only theory is that the folks at Google, for some reason, decided to have ALL notes load at the same time and that's what's slowing down the whole app. The microscopic scrollbar on the right side seems to be evidence of this. I don't know why they would do this instead of the lazy load approach the regular Google Keep website uses, but it really starts to p*ss me off. Is there a way to make this constant freezing stop?

Answer (score 2):

You could try deleting your notes. :D

If you don't want to delete them, you can archive them.  You probably don't need all those notes all the time.  Archiving removes it from the home screen, but you can view it when you need to by going to archives.

Comment: You saved my day!! I've been struggling with this annoying situation for a long time. I didn't know about the archive feature. Now my initial screen has fewer elements and google keep is much faster! Excellent!!